# Dealing with commonly misdiagnosed problems (X is doing Y, but it's really caused by unmentioned Z)

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

There's a question that comes up fairly commonly in the [sass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sass) tag where the compiler is commonly accused of removing vendor prefixes.  Problem is, Sass doesn't actually do this.  It is almost entirely caused by Autoprefixer, an application that is commonly run *after* Sass finishes compiling as part of the OP's build process, but is never mentioned in the question.

I've been voting to close these as "not reproducible" in the past (because Sass never does what they're claiming), but I've seen so many of them now that it's become difficult to ignore.  Should I continue closing these as not reproducible? Or is it worth closing these as duplicates?

Examples:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34524177/having-trouble-with-create-crossbrowsing-keyframes-mixins
- [Compass filter out -moz vendor prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21282722/compass-filter-out-moz-vendor-prefix)
- [Compass (SASS) not adding vendor-prefixes to linear-gradient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23588628/compass-sass-not-adding-vendor-prefixes-to-linear-gradient)
- [SASS stripping out -moz-box-sizing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25087411/sass-stripping-out-moz-box-sizing)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32179803/rails-removing-css-vendor-prefixes-in-production-enviroment

Comment: The answer in the third link seems to give a clue why it happens without people knowing where to point the finger: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23588628/compass-sass-not-adding-vendor-prefixes-to-linear-gradient - scaffolding software, or as I call it: blissful ignorance tools, might be at the root of evil.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I think, the right way will be:

1. Write or find an canonical answer about configuring autoprefixer.
2. Close these questions as duplicates.
3. Add missing tag to these questions.

If a lot of people are asking this, the answer will be much more useful, then saying it is not reproducible as not all information is provided in the question.

Comment: An example of a canonical duplicate I wrote specifically as a dupe close target: http://stackoverflow.com/q/19896870/1189885